# Add global key binding in C in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, x11

I want to create an application in which you load a bunch of files (12 maximum) and then press in firefox/gedit/chrome... f[n] to paste the content of the [n]th file.

I was able to write the content loader and the "keylogger" in C. However I am not sure how to bind the pasting thing to the f1, f2 .. f12 keys globally.

And is what I am doing key binding or is called something else, and could someone please post a sample code of the binding?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you intend to run your application under X11 ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yes most probably

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you want to create an x event; I would imagine that you would configure the keybinding using your window manager. Your script would handle the event and then use something like Crikey:

http://www.shallowsky.com/software/crikey/

Crikey would pass the generated event on to the application. An example would be something like:

alt-f12 crikey '`cat myfile`'

Where a hypothetical alt-f12 event would be bound to crikey '`cat myfile`'. The end result being as if you had typed the contents of myfile into whatever X application had focus at the time.

Comment: I will look in the source code of crikey and take whatever I am interested in. Is there a license on it? I can't seem to find one, thank you for the answer :)